# commands in .bash-profile do not work

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I added an alias in my .bash_profile file in my home directory on Mac Leopard. For example,

```
alias preview = "open -a preview"
alias lsall = "ls -l"
```

When I try to run these commands from the command line, I get the message that `command not found`

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: Sorry! Will go there to see what belongs there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to lose the spaces around `=`, i.e.

```
alias preview="open -a preview"
alias lsall="ls -l"
```

You also need to name the file `.bash_profile` if you want it to be executed automatically when you start a new shell.